# Need help finding a syntax error

Tags: php, jquery

I have an error thrown stating "An error has occurred making the request: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" After some research I found that there is a syntax error. I can't find my syntax error and I need a fresh pair of eyes. Can anyone see it?

jQuery code:

```js
$('#searchTable tr').click(function(){
    var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "classes/get-apn.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
        //timeout: 30000,
        type: "GET",
        data: { parcel_id : 'parcel_id' },
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
        },
        success: function(data){
            //do stuff here on success
            alert('<?php echo $data; ?>');                  
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
header("content-type:application/json");
require('db-connections.php');

$i = isset($_GET['parcel_id']) ? $_GET['parcel_id']: null;

class Apn {

    public function GetApn () {
        $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
        $sql = "select apn from lcv where id=" . $i;
        $data = $db->query($sql);

        print_r($data);//print data for checking
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: which line syntax error?

Comment: It's probably this: `alert('<?php echo $data; ?>');`. Also, you're not posting `parcel_id` value but the string `'parcel_id '`. Try this instead: `data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },`.

Comment: From where $i came in Apn class?

Comment: If you do a direct request from your browser to `classes/get-apn.php?parcel_id=[some valid id]`, do you still see the error syntax?

Comment: I've just looked over the source for this *ezsql_mysql* I wouldn't recommend using it.. Infact, i'd recommend using `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: see php_error in %temp%

Comment: And if you google that you learned that JavaScript throws that error, you're missing a semicolon on line 10.

Comment: Hint: There are several errors in this code. The error you are thinking of is @UselessIntern's answer

Comment: WOW thanks @UselessIntern !! stupid semicolons lol :P

Comment: @Billy please let me know my errors. Thanks!

Comment: The answers below discover several semantic errors such as Asenar and Seunhaab discovered.

Comment: as @Asenar said in his answer you should echo valid json by using `echo json_encode($data);` instead of `print_r($data);` and also `$i` isn't available inside your GetApn function, as void main commented. Also you are passing a string not a variable to your ajax data parameter

Comment: @Billy I don't understand. The variable is declared at the top `$i = isset($_GET['parcel_id']) ? $_GET['parcel_id']: null;`.

Comment: @maryjane9110024 and that isn't in the same scope as the function, so the variable isn't available there. I suggest you fix your code and ask a new question if there is something else you don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Your php script starts with `header("content-type:application/json");` and you use `print_r` at the end, and it's not a valid json.

You should use echo `json_encode($data);` in your php code. If you still have the same error, this may be caused by a php warning/notice which can "break" the valid json format.

**EDIT**: more explanation.

The php code is correct, but the problem is what jquery expect vs the php output:

1. jquery require json (`dataType: 'json'` in `$.ajax` options).
2. php declare sending json with `header("content-type:application/json")`, but produce the `print_r` output, which is not a valid json format.

So, ajax.success function is unable to handle the data sended by php, and ajax.error is used instead to handle the error.

Comment: I didn't do it, can't vote one way or another. Thanks!! I didn't know that. Made the change. :)

Comment: There is a 2nd error someone mentioned about your php code but it seems he deleted his answer (it's about the `$i` which should be defined inside your method to make it available in its scope.
If you have other problem, you should comments the php `header()` line to see what's wrong.

Comment: I don't understand. The variable is declared at the top `$i = isset($_GET['parcel_id']) ? $_GET['parcel_id']: null;`. Wouldn't that make it a global variable and available to any function/class in the document?

Comment: only if you use `global $i` in the function/method you need. but globals that's considered as very very bad practice. Don't use it when you can avoid it.

Comment: and by the way, better name for your method would be `__construct();` instead of `Apn()`, but there is article about that everywhere in the Internet.

Comment: This is confusing. For the search the $i variable is declared outside the class and that code works perfect. I dont get it. :(

Comment: why would i use a constructor for a sql query?

Comment: Sorry I read `Apn` instead of `getApn`, mea culpa. but you should change your method by either setting `$i` inside it, either by doing `$apn->getApn($i)` and changing the way you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data: { parcel_id : parcel_id }
```

Comment: TY! I changed that already, haim770 mentioned it in a previous comment. :)

Comment: My bad, didn't see that.

Comment: Answers are solutions to problems, and this paticular one solved a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting `parcel_id` as plain string not variable.

Change it to:

`data: { parcel_id : parcel_id }`

Also,

In php file

Use `json_encode`

Answer (score -1):

Google tells me that this is a JavaScript error, line 10 is missing a semicolon:

```
alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
```

You can solve this with Google,[jshint](http://www.jshint.com/), and Zend Studio.

EDIT FOR THE DOUBTERS, heres the text from the website:

```
Metrics

There are 3 functions in this file.

Function with the largest signature take 3 arguments, while the median is 1.

Largest function has 2 statements in it, while the median is 1.

The most complex function has a cyclomatic complexity value of 1 while the median is 1.
One warning
10  Missing semicolon.
One undefined variable
1   $
2   $
3   $
Three unused variables
9   textStatus
9   SMLHttpRequest
12  data
JSHint

    About
    Documentation
    Install
    Hack
    Blog

1

        $('#searchTable tr').click(function(){

2

                var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');

3

                $.ajax({

4

                    url: "classes/get-apn.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,

5

                    //timeout: 30000,

6

                    type: "GET",

7

                    data: { parcel_id : 'parcel_id' },

8

                    dataType: 'json',

9

                    error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

10

                        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)

11

                    },

12

                    success: function(data){

13

                        //do stuff here on success

14

                        alert('<?php echo $data; ?>');                  

15

                    }

16

                });

17

            });
```

Comment: semicolon are not required in javascript (but I agree they improve visibility), that's why jshint raise a warning (and not an error).

Comment: The missing semicolon is in this case just a warning but not a syntax error.

Comment: Meh, it's all I can find. The PHP code is syntactically correct and JSLint and JsLint only return this.

Comment: I added explanation in my answer